# is there a simpler way to write this so the latest entry shows and not previous entries?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
if ($row['note_1'] !== '' && $row['note_2'] == '' && $row['note_3'] == '' && $row['note_4'] == '' && $row['note_5'] == '' && $row['note_6'] == '') {
            echo $row['note_1_user'].":<br />";
            echo $row['note_1']; 
        }
        if ($row['note_1'] !== '' && $row['note_2'] !== '' && $row['note_3'] == '' && $row['note_4'] == '' && $row['note_5'] == '' && $row['note_6'] == '') {
            echo $row['note_2_user'].":<br />";
            echo $row['note_2']; 
        }
        if ($row['note_1'] !== '' && $row['note_2'] !== '' && $row['note_3'] !== '' && $row['note_4'] == '' && $row['note_5'] == '' && $row['note_6'] == '') {
            echo $row['note_3_user'].":<br />";
            echo $row['note_3']; 
        }
        if ($row['note_1'] !== '' && $row['note_2'] !== '' && $row['note_3'] !== '' && $row['note_4'] !== '' && $row['note_5'] == '' && $row['note_6'] == '') {
            echo $row['note_4_user'].":<br />";
            echo $row['note_4']; 
        }
        if ($row['note_1'] !== '' && $row['note_2'] !== '' && $row['note_3'] !== '' && $row['note_4'] !== '' && $row['note_5'] !== '' && $row['note_6'] == '') {
            echo $row['note_5_user'].":<br />";
            echo $row['note_5']; 
        }
        if ($row['note_1'] !== '' && $row['note_2'] !== '' && $row['note_3'] !== '' && $row['note_4'] !== '' && $row['note_5'] !== '' && $row['note_6'] !== '') {
            echo $row['note_6_user'].":<br />";
            echo $row['note_6']; 
        }
```

a table with 6 note fields and 6 note user field for a total of 12 fields dealing with notes.  there are other fields, but the notes fields are 12.

in the add note page it's only possible to write to one set at a time.  when going to the page the first time, they add note to field note_1 and the username automatically goes into note_1_user.  then the second time going to the page, the note will go into note_2, and the user automatically goes into note_2_user.  previous notes do not get over-written.

i have a page to view all notes, however, on a different page i just want the latest note to show up.  i can't think of a better way to make that happen other than the way i posted above.

basically every if statement is the same.  they all have the same 6 checks, checking if there is data in the fields, except the first one is checking if one of the 6 is not empty, then the second one checks if two are not empty, and so forth until the last one checks if all 6 are not empty.

this seems like too much code to do this effect.

Comment: Looks like you really need to optimise the database.

Comment: one table 2 fields, note and user, problem solved

Comment: out of curiosity, how can i avoid the dilemma of 2 different users trying to write a note at the same time?  whoever submits form second will overwrite the previous user's note.

Comment: not if each not is in its own row

Comment: if you're trying to solve problem of simultaneous writing, then you current structure will not work for 7 users trying to do this, you need additional table where all notes from all users will be inserted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should really consider changing database structure, but for this case you can use:

```
$lastNoteUser = '';
$lastNoteData = '';
for ($i=1; $i<=6; $i++)
if ( ($row['note_'.$i] != '') && ($row['note_'.$i.'_user'] != '') )
{
    $lastNoteUser = $row['note_'.$i.'_user'];
    $lastNoteData = $row['note_'.$i];
}
if ($lastNoteUser && $lastNoteData)
    echo $lastNoteUser.':<br>'.$lastNoteData;
```